# Org-mode "header-args" and padline

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to get ride of all padlines added during the Org-mode tangle for every kind of code block. So I write this on the top of my file :

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :padline no
```

But the padlines stay there after the tangle.
Next I try this :

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sh :padline no
```

Guess what... it work only for sh code block.
If anyone can help me....
Thanks !

Comment: Did you C-c C-c on the `#+PROPERTY` line  after you added it? Or closed and reopened the file? Or stopped and restarted emacs? You need to alert org about the new property somehow: C-c C-c on the line is the easiest but is also easily forgotten. When I do that, I get no padlines (with sh and python code blocks).

Comment: This was exactly my case. It would be a nice answer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally found the solution. This was due to an out-of-date version of org-mode (I was using the version 8.2.10). In this version the padline header-args does not work (or not implemented I haven't check it). So, just update the org version (now I'm using 9.1.2) and all will be fine.